# how to increase followers in oe_chatter in odoo10

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-10

Any one can tell how to **increase followers in chatter**.. i already create the oe_chatter inside the form and it shown also but **anyone can tell if i add many employee in one2many fields then followers also increases simultaneously**
[image: here follower is one but in one2many field many employees added then followers also increases]
here is my code what i tried yet.

**Py**

`_inherit = ['mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin','utm.mixin']`

**xml**

```
<div class="oe_chatter">
       <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
       <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
</div>
```

Comment: here follower is one but employee names are many. if employee name is 4 then followers also become 4.. how to code for this

Comment: Need to override create and write methods and it you need to add follower ids.

Comment: how it cn be done.. explain with example

Comment: changed my code check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
from odoo import fields,api,models

class your_class(models.Model):
    _name = "hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts"
    _inherit = ['mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin','utm.mixin']

    @api.model 
    def create(self,vals): 
        res = super(hrWorkShifts,self).create(vals) 
        for emp in res.emp_name_ids:
            res.message_follower_ids = [(4,emp.emp_id.id)] 
        return res 

    emp_name_ids = fields.One2many('employee.list','emp_id',string='Employee Name')      

class employee_list(models.Model):
    _name="employee.list"

    emp_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string="Employee Name")
    date   = fields.Date('Date')
```

Put `emp_name_ids` field in view to add employee name and date.

Comment: i gotted ur point bt still i doesn't work. whole chatter is used here but not added in the follower.

Comment: 1. I want oe_chatter which i gotted using _inherit='mail.thread' in .py file and also include div in .xml file. using above code which you edited.            2.After creating oe_chatter. want to add followers according to employee name added. for example see above screen short here employee name are four (david sampson,roger scott,david sampson,david sampson) but after save in follower show only 1 follower (i.e. administrator only) in chatter.  3. final ponit what i want is if there are 4 employee name then after click on save button automtically followers increases to 4.(dat i want).

Comment: Thaks for this description. i will be back to you soon on this.

Comment: employee_ids is one2many field which is employee_name for above screen short..???

Comment: Does that employee_ids one2many of res_partner or hr_employee?

Comment: i use hr_shifts_line = fields.One2many('hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts_lines','hr_shifts_ids',
  string='Hr Work Shifts') and emp_name_ids = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',string='Employee Name',required=True,)

Comment: Ohh.. you need res.partner to perform this operation. because, message_follower_ids is one2many of res.partner not hr.employee.

Comment: @api.model
 def create(self,vals): 
     res = super(CLASSNAME,self).create(vals)
     res.message_follower_ids = [(6,0,res.partner.ids)]
     return res is tdiz correct???

Comment: No no. i mean that you should have one2many field of res.partner not hr.employee.  emp_name_ids = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string='Employee Name',required=True,)

Comment: if take  emp_name_ids = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string='Employee Name',required=True,) then it gives error:-DETAIL:  Key (emp_name_ids)=(2) is not present in table "res_partner".

Comment: Wait a second which field you are using to add more than one employee names.. is it emp_name_ids = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',string='Employee Name',required=True,)  ??

Comment: yes. in employee tree view there is Employee Name and Date . if Employee Name added then followers increases. and Employee Name field is:= emp_name_ids = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',string='Employee Name',required=True,)

Comment: Then It should be One2many. because we are going to add more then one records in it.

Comment: @api.model
 def create(self,vals): 
   res = super(hrWorkShifts,self).create(vals)
  res.message_follower_ids = [(6,0,res.partner.ids)]
  return res                                                                                          hr_shifts_line = fields.One2many('hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts_lines','hr_shifts_ids',
  string='Hr Work Shifts'), hr_shifts_ids = fields.Many2one('hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts',string="Hr Shifts ids")                                                                emp_name_ids = fields.One2many('res.partner',string='Employee Name'):this one u want to say correct.

Comment: class hrWorkShifts(models.Model):_name = 'hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts'_inherit = ['mail.followers','mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin'],@api.onchange('schedule')
def _onchange_schedule(self):
for item in self.hr_shifts_line:
current=self.env['hr.contract'].search([('employee_id','=',item.emp_name_ids.id)], current.write({'working_hours':self.schedule.id})
@api.depends('hr_shifts_line.emp_name_ids')     
def _emp_name_ids(self):
for item in self.hr_shifts_line: current=self.env['hr.contract'].search([('employee_id','=',item.emp_name_ids.id)]),current.write({'working_hours':self.schedule.id})